# Limit div height with Overflow:Scroll through parent with overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS problem:

```css
.outer{
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
 }

.inner{
  overflow-y: scroll;   
}
```

```html
<div id="outer"> 
  <div>some dynamic content with unknown height</div> 
  <div id="inner">  
    some dynamic content with unknown height
    </div>
  </div>
```

So i want the outer div to fit the height of the window, but my inner div should be scrollable. Problem is, i cant give the inner div a fixed height value because it is filled with dynamic content. Overflow-Scroll apparently does need a height value in order to work, which i can't provide. My only (theoretical) limitation to the inner div's height is the outer div. I can't use a height relative to the parents height, because i do not know the height of the divs that come before.

Comment: The inner div needs a height that the scroll window will be, not the content.  Otherwise there would be no need to scroll in the first place!  Try 100%

Comment: Yes, i do not know the height of the scroll window though. I have some dynamic content before the scroll window and i want the scroll window to fit the rest of its parent

Comment: You want the `#inner` to take the remaining height and if the dynamic content in the div above is high enough, it will push the `#inner` down so that it won't be visible?

Comment: It will not come to that, because if the screen height is that low i will display  a different layout anyway. The dynamic content on the top can be zero to ~ 500px , so it is limited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` to solve that

*Note, I changed the `id` to `class` to match your CSS rules*

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.outer {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: lightgray;
}
.inner {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div>
    some dynamic content with unknown height<br>
    some dynamic content with unknown height<br>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    some dynamic content with unknown height<br>
    some dynamic content with unknown height<br>
    some dynamic content with unknown height<br>
    some dynamic content with unknown height<br>
    some dynamic content with unknown height<br>
    some dynamic content with unknown height<br>
    some dynamic content with unknown height<br>
    some dynamic content with unknown height<br>
    some dynamic content with unknown height<br>
    some dynamic content with unknown height<br>
    some dynamic content with unknown height<br>
    some dynamic content with unknown height<br>
    some dynamic content with unknown height<br>
    some dynamic content with unknown height<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works. I tried it before with angular materials "columns" and it did not work, because the inner div would just "crunch" it's contents. But with custom flex, like you used, it works . Thanks.